# How to navigate to a page with a condition before loading current page?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, navigation

I have a condition to check before loading a page. If the condition holds, I want to navigate to this page before current page is loaded. I made a little research and learned that I cannot use NavigationService in constructor. How can I achieve what I want to do?

```
 if (!App.appSettings.Contains("citySelected"))
 {
     NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Pages/CityList.xaml", UriKind.Relative));         
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the NavigationService cannot be used in a page's constructor, it's possible within its `Loaded` event hanlder:

```
public FirstPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    this.Loaded += (sender, args) =>
    {
        if (whatever == true)
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Pages/SecondPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    };
}
```

Alternatively, the same works in the page's `OnNavigatedTo` method:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    if (whatever == true)
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SecondPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```